# Converting a Map<Integer, Object> to Map<Integer, List<Object>>, without using for loops (java)

Tags: java, optimization, hashmap

As the title says, I am currently implementing the below code (well about to), is their a better way - as this seems a bit nasty.

```
Map<Integer, List<Objects>> allObjectsMap = newHashMap(); //guava 

for(int i=1:i<myVar:i++){

    Map<Integer, Objects> eachObjectMap = getMyObjectMap(i); 

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry:eachObjectMap.entrySet()){

        List objectList  = allObjectsMap.get(entry.getKey())

        if(objectList == null){//will be null the first time
           objectList = newArrayList();//guava
           objectList.add(entry.getValue());
           allObjectsMap.put(entry.getKey(),objectList); 
        }
        else{
           objectList.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to check out Guava's [ListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html).

```
Multimap<Integer, Object> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (int i = 0; i < myVar; i++) {
  multimap.putAll(Multimaps.forMap(getMyObjectMap(i)));
}
Map<Integer, Collection<Object>> allObjectsMap = multimap.asMap();
```

One downside of this approach is that the final result is of type `Map<K, Collection<V>>` and not `Map<K, List<V>>`. However, the [ListMultimap.asMap() Javadoc](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap%28%29) states:

> Though the method signature doesn't
>   say so explicitly, the returned map
>   has List values.

Therefore, some sequence of casts (e.g., `(Map<Integer, List<Object>>) (Map<Integer, ?>)`) would work.

Comment: I don't think you need generic information on ArrayListMultimap.<Integer, Object>create(), a simpler solution would be ArrayListMultimap.create()

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just cast it?  Java erases all type information in the generated code, so it should be enough.

Comment: He doesn't state anywhere that the object in his map are, in fact, lists.  Casting it would just yield a ClassCastException when he retrieves an item from his map.